# Migration xml content from Adobe day to Tridion

Tags: migration

We have to do a migration from adobe day to Tridion.
all content is in xml format.
Any migration utility is available for the same?
and can we store all migrated content in Tridion? do we need any other product to store the content.

Comment: The good news is that Tridion is an XML "native speaker", and also has excellent APIs for getting data in and out. It would help, though, if you could expand on the details a bit. Otherwise the only answer we can give is "Yes - no problem". So, for example, what kind of data are we talking about? How is it organised? Is it multi-lingual, classified with a taxonomy, etc.? What sort of content model do you have: is the data stored in small focussed pieces, or all together?

Comment: Thanks a lot Dominic for reply. I am very new to Tridion. All content is in xml format only. its not multilangual and yes, it has taxonamy. I wanted to know content can be stored in Tridion DB itself or do we need any product to store content?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no first-party (SDL) migration tool from other Content Management Systems into SDL Tridion.

*I've spoken with one vendor that said it can handle importing at an SDL conference. They did not know what BluePrinting was, so be careful with any **third-party** vendor that promises a tool.*

You really should understand Tridion's content model before moving content in from any system (i.e. get training, please). Content will be stored in Tridion's database, but you should not put it there directly. Doing database updates directly against the Content Manager can (most likely will) invalidate Support for that system.

You, a business analyst, or a functional consultant should evaluate the existing and proposed (Tridion) content model and choose either:

- [Manual process](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/how-to-say-goodbye-to-your-migration-tool)
- APIs (specifically the Core Service) - [the more structured, the better](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.nl/2011/06/importing-content-into-tridion.html)

This being said, there have been plenty of migrations from other formats. Your team can seek the assistance of SDL Professional Services, partners, or independent groups that have Tridion expertise.

**Final tip**: I've never seen a one-time import process. Expect a few iterations as content model and requirements change, especially with somewhat unstructured content (e.g. changing an `h2` in rich text into an actual field gets complicated fast with syntax errors, missing HTML, etc.).